# wait until invisibility using page factory doesn't work

Tags: selenium

I have this code:

```
@FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME, using = "loading-class")
WebElement loadingAnimation;
```

When I try to use this line:

```
waitDriver.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(this.loadingAnimation));
```

It throws exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for invisibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.className: loading-container' (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

for some reason it works when I debug the code.

I should mention that this works also:

```
while(true)
        {
            try {
                this.loadingAnimation.isDisplayed();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

How to make it work using Page Factory?

Answer (score 1):

When you implement Page Object pattern and initialize your page with `PageFactory` Selenium offers you the capability of using custom `ElementLocator`. There is `AjaxElementLocator` that is supposed to be used for dynamic elements.

In order to apply your own logic of how to consider your element ready for use, there is a method which default implementation is

```java
protected boolean isElementUsable(WebElement element) {
  return true;
}
```

So you are free to override that one to implement your condition. In a nutshell you need to implement your custom `ElementLocatorFactory` which would be producing `AjaxElementLocator` objects with your customized `isElementUsable` method. Then you would initialize your page with

```java
public class YourPage{

   ...   

   public YourPage(...){
      PageFactory.initElements(new YourCustomLocatorFactory(...), this);
   }

   ...

}
```

You can find here [the completed example of how to wait for certain state of dynamic elements of your page objects not using `ExpectedConditions` utility](https://webelement.click/en/selenium_page_object_expected_conditions).